# Feature request: Side by side question preview

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we have a side by side question preview instead of scrolling back and forth to see if the code formatting,indentation,etc is proper?

Comment: Workaround: rotate your stupidly-wide monitor into portrait configuration.

Comment: :)) How would I watch videos then? :D